# Probability of picking the right answer in a yes no question.

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Suppose two people have a yes / no question that the probability for each of them to answer correctly is $\ p $. Each one answer is independent of the other one. What way is the best for them to pick an answer?

1. Picking one of their answer randomly
2. If they both think the same answer they will say it if they each choose different one they will pick randomly one of their answer and say it.

If I set $\ A_i $ = probability of person $\ i = 1,2 $ answer correctly. $\ B $ will be the event of them picking both the same answer.
$$\ P(B) = ((A_1 \cap A_2)\cup (A_1^c\cap A_2^c))$$
if they just pick randomly is

$$\ P(A_i) =p\\ P(A_1 \cup A_2) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) - P(A_1 \cap A_2) = 2p -p^2 $$

According to the second way, if they both pick the same answer :

$$\ P( right \ answer | \ B) =\frac{P((A_1\cap A_2)\cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{p^2}{p^2+(1-p)^2} $$

and then their last option is

$$\ P( right\ answer  | \ B^c ) = \frac{P((A_1\cup A_2)\cap B^c)}{P(B^c)} = \frac{P((A_1\cup A_2)\cap((A_1\cap A_2^c)\cup(A_1^c \cap A_2)))}{P((A_1\cap A_2^c)\cup(A_1^c\cap A_2))} = \frac{P((A_1\cap A_2^c)\cup(A_1^c\cap A_2))}{P((A_1\cap A_2^c)\cup(A_1^c\cap A_2))} = 1 $$

Which is wrong.. Yet I couldn't find what am I missing?

Comment: Neither is good if $p<1/2$.

Comment: How can they be independent?  Presumably the answers are both dependent on the true answer.

Comment: The probability $P[A_1 \cup A_2]$ is the probability that either person 1 or person 2 answers correctly, and is not relevant to this problem; it does not represent a probaiblity of being correct given you randomly select one of the persons.

Comment: @Michael so if they pick random answer, how do I define the probability of the answer to be correct?

Comment: To stress;  The meaning of "independence" is not at all clear here.  Assuming that the two responses aren't entirely random (in which they tell you nothing about the true answer) then knowing that the first person says $T$ is evidence that the true answer is in fact $T$ which would then increase the probability that the second person also says $T$.  So, the answers have to be dependent.  You need to understand the nature of the dependence in order to compute the probabilities of various outcomes.

Comment: @lulu the answers are independent. That's one of the assumptions of the questions. $\ 0 < p < 1 $

Comment: @lulu If you know the first person answered the question correctly, you cannot improve your estimate of the probability with which the second person answers the question correctly. It is still $p$. This is what “independent” means. The probability $p$ in this question is the probability of correctly answering the question, not the probability of giving a particular answer from the set $\{T,F\}$. But even so, if it were the latter, knowing the first person said $T$ would not allow you to predict the second person’s answer any better, assuming you know each probability of a $T$ answer was $p$.

Comment: @bm1125 By the law of total probability, for any event $A$ we have $$ P[A] = P[A|\mbox{pick 1}]P[\mbox{pick 1}] + P[A|\mbox{pick 2}]P[\mbox{pick 2}]$$

Comment: @Michael then I will get exactly the same answer. I can just write $\ P(A_1) = P(A_1 \cap A_2^c) + P(A_1 \cap A_2) = p \cdot (1-p) + p^2 = p $ I don't understand how is that getting me closer to the answer?

Comment: The answer to that question is $p$, it is not $2p-p^2$.  It is not $p$ for the reason you gave, rather, if we randomly pick one of the two (equallly likely) and take that as the answer we get $P[correct] = P[correct|pick1](1/2)+P[correct|pick2](1/2)$.

Comment: By pick1 do you mean person 1 pick the correct answer??